# Separating two strings if any character is encountered

Tags: c#, string

How can I separate **www.myurl.com/help,mycustomers**  into **www.myurl.com/help** and **mycustomers** and put them in different string variables?

Comment: What do you mean by "any character"? It sounds like you just want to split by commas. Have you looked at `string.Split`?

Comment: it can be a comma or a hash...

Comment: Try to be more clear the next time. now we have 4 answers that need to be updated for the 'hash' bit.... And by the way what is for you an hash?

Comment: my app reads some kind of qrcode and gets a string...it should extract substrings separated by hash or comma @Steve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
string MyString="www.myurl.com/help,mycustomers";
string first=MyString.Split(',')[0];
string second=MyString.Split(',')[1];
```

If MyString contains multiple parts, you can use:

```
string[] CS = MyString.Split(',');
```

And each parts can be accessed like:

```
CS[0],CS[1],CS[2]
```

For example:

```
 string MyString="www.myurl.com/help,mycustomers,mysuppliers";
 string[] CS = MyString.Split(',');
CS[0];//www.myurl.com/help
CS[1];//mycustomers
CS[2];//mysuppliers
```

If you want to know more about Split function. Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

> it can be a comma or a hash

Then you can use [`String.Split(Char[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
string s = "www.myurl.com/help,mycustomers";
string first = s.Split(new []{',', '#'},
                       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
string second = s.Split(new [] { ',', '#' },
                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];
```

As Steve *[pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797019/separating-two-strings-if-any-character-is-encountered#comment32981751_21797071)*, using indexer might not be good because your string *couldn't have* any `,` or `#`.

You can use `for` loop also like;

```
string s = "www.myurl.com/help,mycustomers";
var array = s.Split(new []{',', '#'},
                    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", i, array[i]));
}
```

Comment: I wish to upvote, but the automatic use of the indexer after the split is not really a good approach. You know, what if no ......

Answer (score 0):

You can have a short and sweet solution to this as :

```
string[] myArray= "www.myurl.com/help,mycustomers".Split(',');
```